# Why is my answer to this count question not working?

Tags: python

> We have a conveyor belt of items where each item is represented by a different number. We want to know, out of two items, which one shows up more on our belt. To solve this, we can use a function with three parameters. One parameter for the list of items, another for the first item we are comparing, and another for the second item. Here are the steps:
>
> 1. Define the function to accept three parameters: the list, the first item, and the second item
> 2. Count the number of times item1 shows up in our list
> 3. Count the number of times item2 shows up in our list
> 4. If item1 shows up more, return item1. Otherwise, return item2

I've since learned there is a much easier way to answer this using the `count` function than what I came up with. But I don't understand why my solution is not producing the desired result.

```
def more_frequent_item(lst,item1,item2):
  countFirst = 0
  countSecond = 0
  for i in lst:
    if lst[i] == item1:
      countFirst += 1
    elif lst[i] == item2:
      countSecond += 1
  if countFirst >= countSecond:
    return item1
  else:
    return item2
#Uncomment the line below when your function is done
print(more_frequent_item([2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3], 2, 3))
```

Expected output:

```
3
```

Actual output:

```
2
```

Comment: You're close. Change `lst[i]` to `i`

Comment: `for i in lst` iterates over the actual values in list i.e. `2,3,3..2,3` and not the index

Comment: Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in lst` iterates over the values in `lst`, not their indices. As such you'll want to compare the two items against `i` directly rather than `lst[i]`.

```
for i in lst:
  if i == item1:
    countFirst += 1
  elif i == item2:
    countSecond += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating `lst` directly, which means you're getting the actual values, not indices into the `list`. But you then look them up as if they are indices in the `list`, which means you repeatedly test the values at index 2 and 3 in your `list`, not the actual `2`s and `3` seen in the `list`.

Change:

```
  for i in lst:
    if lst[i] == item1:
      countFirst += 1
    elif lst[i] == item2:
      countSecond += 1
```

to:

```
  for item in lst:  # Avoiding name i, to avoid implying it's an index
    if item == item1:
      countFirst += 1
    elif item == item2:
      countSecond += 1
```

Also, note, you have an edge case failure. The description says only return `item1` when there are *more* of it than `item2`, you return it when it's more *or* equal to `item2`'s count. The test at the end should be:

```
if countFirst > countSecond:
```

to fix.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `for num in list:`, `num` are the values in the `list`. So you wouldn't need to do `list[num]` to access that value, you would just use `num` directly:

```
def more_frequent_item(lst,item1,item2):
    countFirst = 0
    countSecond = 0
    for i in lst:
        if i == item1:
            countFirst += 1
        elif i == item2:
            countSecond += 1
    if countFirst >= countSecond:
        return item1
    else:
        return item2
#Uncomment the line below when your function is done
print(more_frequent_item([2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3], 2, 3))
```